# How to use mouseover function?

Tags: magento-1.9

I'd like to add mouseover function like this html code.

And this is my header.phtml code

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/twitter.png'); ?>">
```

Can I add mouseover function to header.phtml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add bellow code your header.phtml file**

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title=""><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/twitter.png'); ?>" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/twitter.png'); ?>';" /></a>
```